# Displaying Data from DataGridView in TextBox Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I am creating a program in Visual Basic where I have a DataGridView connected to an access database and I want to select the row and have the items in the row (firstname and surname) to be displayed in a textbox (txtname) when then button select is pressed. I so far have been able to get one column to display so it either displays first name or last name but it wont display both.

```
Dim currentCellData As String
    Dim StaffName As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To staffList.SelectedCells.Count - 1
        Dim colindex = staffList.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex
        Dim rowindex = staffList.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
        currentCellData = staffList.Item(colindex, rowindex).Value.ToString
        StaffName = currentCellData
        txtName.Text = StaffName
    Next
```

Comment: are there 2 columns in total, with one populated with the firstname, and the other populated with the last name?

Comment: @Jaxi yes there are two columns one with the first name and one with the last name

Comment: So you're asking how to concatenate two `Strings`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concatenation, and there is no need for the `for` loop.

This should work if I have understood correctly:

```
txtName.Text = staffList.Item(0, rowindex).Value.ToString & " " & staffList.Item(1, rowindex).Value.ToString
```